# How to write 'Git LFS pull after checkout' settings in the Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I created a configuration file with Jenkins file to configure the Jenkins pipeline.
An error occurred when doing git pull.
The cause was that the groovy file did not have the Git LFS pull after checkout setting.
I do not know how to write Git LFS pull after checkout setting to groovy.

```
git(
　url: git@...,
　branch: "master",
　credentialsId:"abcdefg"
)

// Git LFS pull after checkout setting??
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I was able to use the Git plugin in the pipeline. Refer to the documentation [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/) for more info:

```
        checkout([  $class: "GitSCM", 
            branches: [[name: "refs/heads/${your branch name}"]],
            extensions: [
                [$class: "GitLFSPull"]
            ],
            userRemoteConfigs: [
                [credentialsId: "${your git credential ID}",
                url: "${your git URL}"]
            ]
        ])
```

Considering you are trying to download a large file, you may want to increase the time out limit too (default is set to 10 minutes):

```
        checkout([  $class: 'GitSCM', 
            branches: [[name: 'refs/heads/'+"${branch_or_tag}"]],
            extensions: [[$class: 'GitLFSPull']]
                       +[[$class: 'CloneOption', timeout: 30]],
            userRemoteConfigs: [
                [credentialsId: "${your git credential ID}",
                url: "${your git URL}"]
            ]
        ])
```